# Amazon Athena - can't create table via java JDBC

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jdbc

```
java.sql.SQLException
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. line 1:14: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE TABLE "gjhf"' [Execution ID not available]

Caused by: com.simba.athena.amazonaws.services.athena.model.InvalidRequestException: line 1:14: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE TABLE "gjhf"' (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 5341d5ac-0d24-430c-bcbe-fdedb9c95327)
```

gjhf -> table name

I am trying to create a table in amazon Athena using the JDBC connection. Can Anyone explain why it's caused? And how to fix it?

Comment: Did you put the table name in quotes? If so, try it without quotes. Otherwise, please Edit your question and include your full `CREATE TABLE` statement so that we can try to recreate your situation.

Comment: "create ***external*** table" here ***external*** is the mandatory key. It must be used and not like other SQL queries.

Comment: Are you saying that using `create external table` fixed your problem? If so, please add an Answer so future readers can benefit. You are welcome to Answer your own Question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, when I'm trying to post an answer stack overflow throws me an error "Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question." Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Now I have posted the new question on amazon athena insert query issue with a piece of code. I think you can give it a try and help me fix that.